# How do I use GCC options -iprefix and -iwithprefix?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a c++ application that is separated into modules. The directory structure for each module looks like this:

```
module_a/
  export/  <-- module_a public interface
  src/     <-- module_a private source
  test/
    src/   <-- unittests for module_a
```

I'm using CMake to setup the module dependencies and to build the application. If `module_a` depends on `module_b` then `module_b`'s `export` directory is added as include path when building `module_a`.

So, if there is a file `module_b/export/foo.h` that `module_a` needs then in a source file you will use `#include "foo.h"`.

I'm looking for a way to to make so that the module name is part of the include directive. So for the above example I want to (have to) write `#include "module_b/foo.h"`.

Is this something that can be done with GCC option -iprefix and -iwithprefix? I've searched for usage examples but all I can find is copies and references back to the GCC manual, which I think doesn't explain it very well.

I have tried to use it this way:

```
$ find -type f
./src
./src/main.cc
./export
./export/bar.h

$ g++ -iprefix foo/ -iwithprefix export/ src/main.cc
src/main.cc:1:10: fatal error: foo/bar.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "foo/bar.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 9.2.1-17) 9.2.1 20191102
```

But as you can see, it doesn't work. How should I use -iprefix and -iwithprefix?

Also, does anyone have another solution to my problem? I'm a bit worried that IDEs and other compilers might not understand -iprefix and -iwithprefix, so any other solutions are welcome as well.

Edit: after posting this question I immediately realized that perhaps `-iprefix foo/ -iwithprefix bar` is just a fancy way of writing `-I foo/bar`. However, I tested that and I still didn't get it to work. So it would still be good if someone could explain how these options works, even if they are not going to help me for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I use -iprefix and -iwithprefix?

It's just a shortcut to avoid having to write out a common prefix every time. So instead of:

```
cpp -Idirafter /sys/root/a -Idirafter /sys/root/b
```

You instead do:

```
cpp -iprefix /sys/root/ -iwithprefix a -withprefix b
```

*(substitute `-Iwithprefix` for `-Iwithprefixbefore` if you want it to be equivalent to `-I` instead.)*

This can come on handy with very long include directory paths like you may run into when cross-compiling (and may be even required, cf. `getconf ARG_MAX`)

> Also, does anyone have another solution to my problem?

I stumbled upon `-iprefix`, because I've the same problem you have as well and hoped there would be an out-of-the-box option for that. There isn't, but Linux device tree builds have the same issue:

The device trees for `ARCH=arm` and `ARCH=arm64` are in `arch/arm/boot/dts` and `arch/arm64/boot/dts`, respectively. Sometimes, arm64 device trees need some common file from the arm directory, but having the `dts` directories of all architectures in path isn't that great a solution.

What Linux does instead, is [having a dedicated directory in the source tree](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.2/source/scripts/dtc/include-prefixes) with suitably-named symlinks into each architecture and this directory's path as well as the directory of the currently active `ARCH` [go into the search path](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d5d332d3f7e8435e264a71b90178dee69428d630). That way, `ARCH=arm` can write `#include "something.dtsi"`, but `ARCH=arm64` has to write `#include <arm/something.dtsi>` instead.